# FFT Resolution in constrained environments

Tags: c, embedded, real-time, signal-processing, fft

So I am sampling data from a sensor at 10 kilo samples per second. I am going to collect 512 samples continuously from this sensor, and then try to do an FFT on it. But here is the problem, I am constrained to do a 16 point FFT on it. So from what I understand is that I divide my 512 samples' frame into bins of 16, and take FFT on them individually. Once I have done that, I just merge them side by side.

My questions:

If my sampling frequency is 10 kilo samples per second, and my FFT size is 16, then my bin size should be 625 Hz, right?

Second, am I correct in merging the FFT outputs as above?

I will be absolutely grateful for a response.

Comment: You're correct about the bin size, but what do you mean by "merge them side by side" ?

Comment: How come you are limited to a 16-point FFT?

Answer (score 3):

You could also do 2 layers of radix-16 FFTs and bit shuffles, plus 1 layer of radix-2 FFT butterflys to produce the same result as an FFT of length 512.

Comment: hotpaw2: This sounds beautiful. Any links for a broader understanding?

Answer (score 1):

If you collect data in 512-sample chunks but are constrained to 16-point FFT, you will have to perform the FFT 32 times for each chunk and average the results (either for each chunk or for the entire recording - your choice).

The sampling rate determines the upper limit of the frequency values you assign to the FFT results, and it doesn't matter whether you are looking at 512 samples or 16 samples at a time. Your top frequency is going to be 1/2 the sample rate = 5 kHz.

The series of frequency results will be (in Hz) ...

5000
2500
1250 
625
312.5
...
and so on, depending on how many samples you pass to the FFT.

I'm not going to ask why you're restricted to 16-point FFT!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using 16-point FFT, then the resolution you will get is low. It will be able to capture frequencies from 0-5 Sa/s with only 8 unique bins.

Regarding your question about the bin size, I don't understand why you need it.

I think to get better results, you can also average the sampled points to fit your 16-point FFT.